# How to keep the login active Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm having some difficulties in being able to keep the login active in my app, either by email or by google account. I've tried using the SharedPreferences method but not having much success.

This is the login button code:

```
DefaultButton(
    text: "Continuar",
    press: () async {
      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        _formKey.currentState.save();
        try {
          KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
          UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email,
              password: password);               
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil( 
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Tabs()),  
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'user-not-found') { 
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Nenhum usuário encontrado para esse e-mail.");
            print('Nenhum usuário encontrado para esse e-mail.');
          } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
            Fluttertoast.showToast( 
                msg: "Senha errada fornecida para esse usuário.");
            print('Senha errada fornecida para esse usuário.');
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ),
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this below? This will save your user auth state. 
final Stream<User?> firebaseUserChanges = firebaseAuth.userChanges();

Answer (score 0):

firebase authentication has `currentUser` property. You need to check it when the app started. Check the documentation
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#user-management

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if(user == null){
// go to login page
} else {
// go to home page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use provider package. You could create Auth class like this:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


 Future singInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;

      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create AuthUser class, example

```
 class AuthedUser {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String photoUrl;

  AuthedUser({this.uid, this.name, this.email, this.photoUrl});
}
```

Then you can create AuthedUser instance with the Firebase user and then listen to auth state changes.

```
  AuthedUser _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    print(user);
    return user != null
        ? AuthedUser(
            uid: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName == null ? 'no name' : user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            photoUrl: user.photoURL == null ? null : user.photoURL)
        : null;
  }
  // auth change user stream

  Stream<AuthedUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
}
```

Then you could create Widget, which listens to the stream and for example returns Login Widget if no user or Nav widget if there is logged user.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<AuthedUser>(context);
print(user);
if (user == null) {
  return Register();
} else {
  return Nav();
}}
```

Finally you just call

```
await AuthService()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password)
```